# Music meets DSP: What is the difference between Frequency, Pitch, Tone and Note

Tags: signal-processing, frequency, pitch

I am working through some DSP, in regard to writing music related software,  and am getting confused by terminology.

I am starting to wonder whether these entities are inherently confusing / handwavey / loosely defined...

**Frequency** is clear:  Cycles per second, Hz.

**Pitch**, **Tone** and **Note** are not clear to me.

In addition to these terms, there is '**pitch-class**'.  C4 and C5 are said to be in the same pitch class.

Also, are there any **other terms** that need to be added to this collection for disambiguation?

Comment: You are asking about music/sound terms, so this is not really a programming question. Voting to close as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pitch represents the perceived frequency of a sound. Pitch is used in musical context, while frequency in technical. Note is also musical term. Note is sound with frequency that is not generic, but one from scale. For example Middle A is the 440 Hz. All other A's will be `440 * 2 ^ x`. The series: .. 110, 220, 440, 880.. (A's in all octaves) form Pitch class.

> A musical tone is a steady periodic
>   sound. A musical tone is characterized
>   by its duration, pitch, intensity (or
>   loudness), and timbre (or quality).

Comment: "Pitch" is the *perceived* frequency; it's a subjective quantity.

Answer (score -1):

Frequency (technical) = Pitch  (music)
Musical Note = Tone

An explanation of the concepts: [Frequency, Wavelength, and Pitch](http://cnx.org/content/m11060/latest/) and here: [How Acoustic Guitars Work](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/guitar2.htm).

Also Wikipedia is your friend.